# Determine total size of SVN directory and store in python variable

Tags: python, awk

this prints the directory size, but how can i save the output to a python variable, instead of print.

```
svn list -vR http://myIP/repos/test | awk '{sum+=$3; i++} END {print sum/1024000}'
```

but i need to store this print in a python variable;

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(svnproc, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = proc.stdout.read()
Print str(output)
```

nasty workaround is the push it out to a file and cat the file

```
svn list -vR http://myIP/repos/test | awk '{sum+=$3; i++} END {> /tmp/output.txt}'
```

Comment: Is the `output` variable there not exactly what you are asking for? Or is the question how to do the equivalent of that awk command on the string in the variable?

Comment: Hi Andrey, output variable is blank

Comment: Is `svnproc` a string or a sequence? This sounds like you are just `subprocess` incorrectly somehow.

Comment: its a string of steps that are doing multiple operations

Answer (score 0):

From the fine docstring of "subprocess" I can read:

> ### Replacing shell pipe line
>
> output=`dmesg | grep hda`

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

so that in your case I'd try the following code

```
switches  = ...
directory = ...

p1 = Popen(["svn", "list", switches, directory], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["awk", "{sum+=$3; i++} END {print sum/1024/1024}", stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0].strip()
```

ps: I have changed from `sum/1024000` to `sum/1024/1024` assuming that you want to count in megabytes

"

Answer (score 0):

```
svnproc = "svn list -vR " + repoURL + " | awk '{sum+=$3; i++} END {print sum/1073741824}'"
proc = subprocess.Popen(svnproc, shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
svnbackupsize = float(proc.stdout.read())
```

The only problematic part of this script is that Popen does not wait till the process is DONE, however subprocess.call does wait till the process is completed.